# iOS 6 send passes via push

Tags: ios, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook

It is possible to send passes via Apple Push Notifications directly? I know about the update function of passes via push. But I need to send the whole pass from a server after the user orders the ticket from an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, because the user should choose to add passes to their passbook, but why not show the pass in a `PKAddPassesViewController` while the user is still in the app? If the pass is issued well after the user's order is submitted, you could show a push notification saying the pass is ready, and to tap the push notification to show the pass.

Comment: Because of an possible delay between order and validation. The validation process can take up to an hour or more.

Comment: In that case, you could do as I suggested, and push a notification to your app that the pass is ready to be picked up.

Comment: ".. and to tap the push notification to show the pass." could you explain this part? So, if the user tap the push the app is launching and send request to the server to get the pass in the response? Do I need to open the app?

Comment: If the user presses the "View" button on an alert, taps a banner or Notification Center table row, or slides an icon on the lock screen, iOS will launch your app and call the app delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. The options dictionary passed will include the push notification's payload dictionary in the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key. You can include a bit of custom data in the push notification to identify that there's a pass to download—but only a little bit, as the space in a push notification is tightly limited.